# Testing promise resolving returned from service

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I've got a problem with testing promise resolving of promise returned from function. The problem is that .then() isn't executed.

Components method that I'm testing:

```js
 private _openToast(): void {
        this._toast
            .action()
            .then(
                () => {
                    this.test();
                },
                () => {}
            );
    }
    
test(): void {
console.log("It's ok")
}
```

Service

```js
@Injectable()
export class ToastService {
    constructor(private _toast: OuterToastService) {}

    action<ValueType>(context?: Partial<IToastContext>, config?: Partial<ToastConfig>): Promise<ValueType> {
        return this._toast.open(); // It's material-like toast service that returns promise
    }
}
```

And test

```js
describe('Component', () => {
    let component: Component;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<Component>;
    const MockToastService = jasmine.createSpyObj('toast', ['action']);
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [Component],
            providers: [
                { provide: ToastService, useValue: MockToastService },
            ],
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });
    })

it('should call test() if toast accepted', () => {
            MockToastService.action.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve());
            const spy = spyOn<any>(component, 'test');

            component['_openToast']();
            expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
```

Result of running test is:
`Expected spy test to have been called.`
Which means (I believe so) that .then() isn't executed. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which means (I believe so) that .then() isn't executed. Why?

Your test is entirely synchronous, so it's not giving time for `this.test()` to be called. The promise returned by MockToastService may be in a resolved state, but the `.then` callback still runs asynchronously, the next time microtasks are run.

To fix this, you'll need to make openToast return a promise, and then have your test wait for that promise:

```
private _openToast(): void {
  return this._toast.action().then(
    () => {
      this.test();
    },
    () => {}
  );
}

it("should call test() if toast accepted", () => {
  MockToastService.action.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve());
  const spy = spyOn<any>(component, "test");

  return component["_openToast"]().then(() => {
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Alternatively, you can use a [fakeAsync](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync) test, and then force the microtask queue to flush:

```
import { fakeAsync, flushMicrotasks } from '@angular/core/testing';

it("should call test() if toast accepted", fakeAsync(() => {
  MockToastService.action.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve());
  const spy = spyOn<any>(component, "test");

  component["_openToast"]();

  flushMicrotasks();

  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

Comment: It does work, but I wonder if there is any other way without interfering with the components method?

Comment: You could use fakeAsync instead. I've added in an example